# How can I bit-convert between Int and Word quickly?

Tags: haskell, integer, cpu-word

The [Haskell `base` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Word) says that "A Word is an unsigned integral type, with the same size as Int."

How can I take an `Int` and cast its bit representation to a `Word`, so I get a `Word` value with the same bit representation as the original `Int` (even though the number values they represent will be different)?

I *can't* use `fromIntegral` because that will change the bit representation.

I *could* loop through the bits with [the `Bits` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#t:Bits), but I suspect that will be very slow - and I don't need to do any kind of bit manipulation. I want some kind of function that will be compiled down to a no-op (or close to it), because no conversion is done.

### Motivation

I want to use [`IntSet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-IntSet.html) as a fast integer set implementation - however, what I really want to store in it are `Word`s. I feel that I could create a `WordSet` which is backed by an `IntSet`, by converting between them quickly. The trouble is, I don't want to convert by value, because I don't want to truncate the top half of `Word` values: I just want to keep the bit representation the same.

Comment: [`unsafeCoerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce) seems to do the trick actually, but I'm not sure it's to be trusted.

Comment: The documentation for [`unsafeCoerce#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:unsafeCoerce-35-) suggests that it can be (since casting between same-size unboxed types is supported). I do prefer `int2Word#` and `word2Int#` for being more explicit, though - better to have the compiler's vocal support.

Comment: Are you sure that `fromIntegral` changes the bit representation?  For example, when I use ghci to run `fromIntegral (2147483648 :: Word32) :: Int32`, it returns `-2147483648`, which is the correct equivalent bit representation.

Comment: That is a [strange implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#line-401) which does indeed do bit conversion - and I confess to not having tried it, because that behaviour is completely surprising and not at all what I would expect from `fromIntegral`.

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel In fact, `fromIntegral :: Int -> Word` *does* preserve bit-pattern, and the same holds for `fromIntegral :: Word -> Int`. Since `fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger` and `Integer` has a bad representation for integers between  `2^(WORD_SIZE_IN_BITS-1)< x < 2^WORD_SIZE_IN_BITS - 1`, this looks like a value conversion, but this is bit-pattern-preserving in values. To a better performance, the implementation has a GHC Rewrite Rule that replaces `fromInteger` with `int2Word#` and `word2Int#`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int2Word#`/`word2Int#` in `GHC.Prim` perform bit casting. You can implement wrapper functions which cast between boxed `Int`/`Word` using them easily.